# String.fromCharCode(132) returns empty string

Tags: javascript, string, unicode, fromcharcode

I'm trying to make an encryption system that take the  char code of every character in a string then applies a function to them to create new char codes. Then, make string from those char codes. every thing is successful, but I've noticed that when `String.fromCharCode` is called on `132` it returns an empty string. is there  way to fix this?

i've tried:

```
'\u{132}' // works but '\u{132}.charCodeAt(0)' returns 306
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're working in two different number systems. charCode is in decimal, but `\u` notation uses hexadecimal.   306 is the decimal representation of the hexadecimal `\u{132}`:

```js
console.log('\u{132}'.charCodeAt(0)) // returns in decimal
console.log(parseInt(132, 16)) // convert hex to decimal

console.log('\u{132}') // the character represented in hex
console.log(String.fromCharCode(306)) // and represented in decimal
```

`String.fromCharCode(132)` actually returns a [control code](https://www.codetable.net/name/control-0084), not an empty string.